# Deploying my website to the pulic using IIS and windows server

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, hosting

I recently bought a domain. Let's say my domain is "domain.com", and I made a website in visual web dev. using ASP.NET and VB.NET. I also have an old computer that I turned into a home server so I installed windows server 2008 R2 SP2. So I uploaded my website to a folder and went to the IIS manager. There I added a website, set the sitename to "domain.com" application pool to "ASP.NET v4.0". Then the physical path to: "c:\websites\wwwroot\domain.com" then in the bindings I added 3 different things.

```
type   hostname     port   IP adress
http www.domain.com  80   my IP found at www.what'smyip.com
http domain.com      80   my IP found at www.what'smyip.com
http   *blank*       80   192.168.1.6(my server's internal IP)
```

I made sure port 80 is open in my router and I added a firewall inbound rule for port 80.

When I connect using 192.168.1.6 I get my website and everthing works like it should.

However when I connect using domain.com or www.domain.com I see a 404 page. http://prntscr.com/42ynf4

Also when I change my bindings and I change the IP for domain.com and www.domain.com like displayed below:

```
type   hostname     port   IP adress
http www.domain.com  80   192.168.1.6(my server's internal IP)
http domain.com      80   192.168.1.6(my server's internal IP)
http   *blank*       80   192.168.1.6(my server's internal IP)
```

It works just like it's supposed to?

I have done a DNSlookup on the domain and it's active. I'm a little bit stuck on this and I know you guys aren't experts on hosting but you all probably have more knowledge about this then I do.

Comment: Are you forwarding the port 80 in your router to the IP address of your web server (192.168.1.6)? Also, I don't know where you bought your domain but did you point your domain to your public IP?

Comment: the domain is pointing at my IP adress yes. And I only forwarded the port for 192.168.1.6, I shouldn't need to open port 80 on my laptop do I?

Comment: Are you sure that your external IP is static? For a domestic connection it wouldn't usually be.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what is the server IP address (netstat), because you could use a proxy and then the Internet IP info will be not correct.
Also, make sure that you set the correct home page in IIS.